# Progress-OpenEdge query to show Column Relations of the table

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I want a query to get the **column relation** or **reference of column** for the **table** or for **all the databases**.

Like in **MySQL**, we have a **query**

> SELECT * FROM **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE** WHERE
> **TABLE_SCHEMA** = 'database_name';

So, What is the query for **Progress OpenEdge** to get column relation.

Also where are **procedure, functions and views** stored in **ProgressDB**?

**Query** to view **database** name **list**?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference-117/page/OpenEdge-SQL-System-Catalog-Tables.html ?

Comment: Thanks @StefanDrissen for the link. I was not able find it.

Comment: @StefanDrissen, How can we get database name list?

Comment: One port provides access to a single database, so I do not understand what you mean with a database name list.

Comment: @StefanDrissen, Is it that we can't create more than one Database? If So, then can you help me with getting that database name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find relationships, or views, or stored procedures you must query the meta-schema. Stefan's link documents SYSTABLES, SYSCOLUMNS, SYSINDEXES, SYSPROCEDURES, and SYSVIEWS. These are the tables that define what you have asked for.

https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference-117/page/OpenEdge-SQL-System-Catalog-Tables.html

The Progress database does not explicitly store relationships.  They are implied, by convention, when there are common field names between tables but this does not create any special relationship in the engine. You can parse the tables above and make some guesses but, ultimately, you probably need to refer to the documentation for the application that you are working with.

Most Progress databases were created to be used by Progress 4gl applications. SQL came later and is mostly used to support 3rd party reporting tools. As a result there are two personas - the 4gl and sql.  They have have many common capabilities but there are some things that they do not share. Stored procedures are one such feature. You can create them on the sql side but the 4gl side of things does not know about them and and will not use them to enforce constraints or for any other purpose. Since, as I mentioned, most Progress databases are created to support a 4gl application, it is very unusual to have any sql stored procedures.

(To make matters even more complicated there is some old sql-89 syntax embedded within the 4gl engine. But this very old syntax is really just token sql support and is not available to non-4gl programs.)

Comment: Thanks @TomBascom, Can you help me with query to get all database name in Progress database?